# Create an array from a tuple

Tags: rust

I can create an array from a tuple like this:

```
let a = (1, 2, 3);
let b = [a.0, a.1, a.2];
```

Is there a way to do it without naming each element of the tuple? Something like:

```
let b = a.to_array();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such functionality *at the moment*, however it would be perfectly possible to extend the set of implementations of the `From` trait to cover this usecase (and its reverse).

This extension would have to be in the `core` crate because of the orphan rules, but we can readily demonstrate it with custom traits:

```
use std::convert::Into;

trait MyFrom<T> {
    fn my_from(t: T) -> Self;
}

trait MyInto<U> {
    fn my_into(self) -> U;
}

impl<T, U> MyInto<U> for T
    where
        U: MyFrom<T>
{
    fn my_into(self) -> U { <U as MyFrom<T>>::my_from(self) }
}

impl<T> MyFrom<()> for [T; 0] {
    fn my_from(_: ()) -> Self { [] }
}

impl<T, A> MyFrom<(A,)> for [T; 1]
    where
        A: Into<T>,
{
    fn my_from(t: (A,)) -> Self { [t.0.into()] }
}

impl<T, A, B> MyFrom<(A, B)> for [T; 2]
    where
        A: Into<T>,
        B: Into<T>,
{
    fn my_from(t: (A, B)) -> Self { [t.0.into(), t.1.into()] }
}
```

Once define, it's easy enough to use:

```
fn main() {
    {
        let array: [i64; 0] = ().my_into();
        println!("{:?}", array);
    }
    {
        let array: [i64; 1] = (1u32,).my_into();
        println!("{:?}", array);
    }
    {
        let array: [i64; 2] = (1u32, 2i16).my_into();
        println!("{:?}", array);
    }
}
```

will print:

> ```
> []
> [1]
> [1, 2]
> ```

The reverse implementation would be as easy, there's nothing mysterious here it's just boilerplate (hurray for macros!).

Answer (score 6):

As of 1.71, there are `impl<T> From<(T, T)> for [T; 2]` and `impl<T> From<[T; 2]> for (T, T)` for arities up to 12.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't. What is more, you can't even iterate over tuples. The tuple is heterogeneous, so it's unfit for a conversion to a homogeneous type like a vector or an array.

You could write a macro to allow iteration over the contents of a tuple of a generic length and collect them (as long as all its elements are of the same type), but you would still have to access/process every element individually.

Comment: yeah, its because of the type system right? because even been a tuple, `(int, int, int)` is not the same type as `(int, int)`,  and since there is no way of unpacking it iterating you cant really move it to an array.

Comment: @DanielSanchez: exactly - a tuple's type is determined by both its length and the types of its contents. Even languages with higher-kinded types like Haskell don't provide such functionalities.

Comment: I disagree with your statement that a tuple being a heterogeneous type is unfit for a conversion to an array (a homogeneous type). While highly probably, it fails to account for the interesting cases where the conversion makes sense: ie the tuple has the same number of elements as the array and each element of the tuple is convertible to the type of elements the array contains.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: true; I meant in general.

Comment: @ljedrz: Yes, I understood. Picking any two random tuple type and array type it's likely the conversion is nonsensical. However whenever a developer wants to go from one to the other, it's likely that (1) the lengths match and (2) the types match, or are convertible.